# How to get href of a tag with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I  want to get id that exist into `href` attribute of `a` tag in my page.I want first prevent of post back page and then do this work.
The a tags such as this:

`'<a href="/ArtPlaces/Delete/5">حذف</a>'`

```
$('a:contains("حذف")').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = this.href;
    var splitHref = href.split("/");
    var inedxDelete = splitHref.length - 1;
    var id = splitHref[inedxDelete];
    alert(id);
});
```

> TypeError: this.href is not a function

I want get `5` number  in the href attribute.Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead use `.getAttribute()` or `.attr()` and you can make use of `[].pop()` method which returns the last added item in the array, So you don't have to calculate the index of it.

```js
$('a:contains("حذف")').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  var num = href.split("/").pop(); // will give you last value of array.
  alert(num);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/ArtPlaces/Delete/5">حذف</a>'
```

Using a regular expression with `.match()` method:

```js
$('a:contains("حذف")').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  var num = href.match(/\d+/g)[0];
  alert(num);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/ArtPlaces/Delete/5">حذف</a>'
```

Comment: well there are other ways too, like regular expressions to extract the numbers out of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working for me. To get `5` use the below given code

```
var splitHref = href.split("/")[5]
```

**As said by Jai in comment**

> this.attr('href') won't work but would create an error as jQuery methods are only for jQuery objects.

**DEMO**

```js
$('a:contains("حذف")').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = this.href;
    var splitHref = href.split("/")[5]
    //var inedxDelete = splitHref.length - 1;
    //var id = splitHref[inedxDelete];
    alert(splitHref);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/ArtPlaces/Delete/5">حذف</a>
```

Comment: just noticed: _`this.attr('href')`_ won't work but would create an error as jQuery methods are only for jQuery objects.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll check and update the answer